# Keycloak implementing both user and app authentication in the same realm

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect

I have a setup like this:

1. Back-end REST API application - *Single* Instance running in Cloud Server **-** Let's call it as **A**
2. Public Users` Mobile app & browser clients **-** Let's call them together as **X**

We already are using Keycloak for Identity and Access Management. As per the current setup,

- **X** to **A** uses **Password grant flow**, that is – a client is created in Keycloak with *Client-Type* as *Public* for user management and auth of **X** to **A**.

Now, we have to introduce new layer of back-end app, that is,

3. Back-end REST API application - *Multiple* Instances running in On-prem Servers across different physical locations **-** Let's call them together as **B**.

Now, both **B** and **X** both are clients of **A**, [i.e. **A** serve both **B** and **X**].

**Please clarify:**

1. Should I create another type of client in the same realm for **B**, like below?

   - **B** to **A**: **Client credentials grant flow** i.e. I have to create another *Client-Type* as *Confidential* for **B** to **A**, to configure a service-account for each of the instances of **B**.

     - If yes, please guide me on how to configure both Auth flows in **A** i.e. **A** has to auth both **B** and **X**.
2. I feel like this one as a bad idea - Using the existing setup as it is, which is explained below.

   As per the new business logic,

   - **X** logs-in the app (mobile/web app) using username and password and calls an API of **A** to generate a QR Code, which will contain the hash of the user's (**X**'s) access token and some other info.
   - **A** stores both hash and access token of **X** in the database
   - **B** gets the hash of the access token used by **X** to access **A**, from the QR Code scanned by the user. **B** uses the hash to validate the authenticity of the QRCode, by calling an API of **A**

   As mentioned in the above business logic, if needed, **A** can expose an API, where the above said user access token can be retrieved through a get request, by sending the hash as a request header param or query. This token can be further used by **B** for further API calls to **A**.

I think that the above idea is bad, because, we are not supposed to send the user access token over the internet, even if there is a SSL/TLS connection between **B** and **A**.

3. Can the *Client-Type*, **Bearer-Only**  be used in this scenario between **B** and **A**? If yes, Please guide me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are having both Public and On prem services as clients, I would suggest the following:

1. As you said, X as public client shall use Password grant
2. B should use Client Credentials mechanism to get itself authenticated with Keycloak. Keycloak will provide it the access token through ${kc.realm-url}/protocol/openid-connect/token endpoint. This access token can be sent to A.
3. "A" should also be a registered client with its own credentials.
4. When "A" receives request from X or B, it should use a mechanism called Token verification through Introspection endpoint where it will get the token verified by calling Keycloak.
   Introspection endpoint expects access token, client id and client secret.

This way, A can be sure that the token received by it is indeed issued by Keycloak.